# how to get chi square distribution to N(0,1)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be  a  random  sample  from chi square distribution.   Let $x̄$ be  the  sample mean.  How would you use the central limit theorem to get this approximation:

$\frac{\left(x̄-1\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}}$ ~ $Normal(0,1)$

also how would one derive a normal approximation for $X=\sum _{i=1}^n X_i$

Comment: Your first question is fine, but your second question doesn't make any sense. What is $X$?

Comment: sorry ill edit it

Comment: By chi squared you must have more specifically meant $\chi_1^2$. Do you know the mean & variance of the $\chi_1^2$ distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## CLT

[One version of the central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) says that if $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots$ are i.i.d. with the same mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^{2}$, then
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\left(\overline{X}_{n}-\mu\right)\xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{N}(0,1)
\qquad\text{as }n\rightarrow\infty
$$
where $\xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}$ denotes convergence in distribution and $\overline{X}_{n}=(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n})/n$.
In this case, convergence in distribution means that the left-hand side's [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) converges to the cumulative distribution function of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

The above suggests that when $n$ is large,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\left(\overline{X}_{n}-\mu\right)
$$
can be approximated by a standard normal random variable.
Stated equivalently, when $n$ is large, we can approximate $\overline{X}_n$ by
$$\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}\right).$$

## Your questions

In your first question, $X_i \sim \chi_1^2$ where $\chi_1^2$ is a chi-squared distribution with parameter $k=1$ (this just means that $X_i$ is a squared standard normal random variable).
In this case, $\mu \equiv \mathbb{E}X_{i}=1$ and $\sigma^2 \equiv \operatorname{Var}X_{i}=2$.

Fixing $n$ large and letting $\overline{X} \equiv \overline{X}_n$ to match your notation, the previous section tells us that we can approximate
$$
\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\left(\overline{X}-1\right)
$$
by a standard normal random variable.
Equivalently, we can approximate $\overline{X}$ by
$$
\mathcal{N}\left(1,\frac{2}{n}\right).
$$

Lastly, you ask how we can approximate $X \equiv X_1 + \cdots + X_n$.
Note that this is just the sample mean multiplied by $n$ (i.e., $X = n\overline{X}$).
It stands to reason that you can approximate this by $\mathcal{N}(n, 2n)$.